# Mantain row names of incidence matrix when creating a graph

Tags: igraph

I have an incidence matrix which represents a chronological list of events (rows): `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, and a list people who met at those events (columns): `A, B, C, D, E`.

I proceeded as following to create a graph where each edge indicates whether a pair of people have met or not:

```
library(igraph)    
incidence.matrix <- matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,
                             1,0,0,0,1,
                             0,1,0,1,0,
                             1,1,0,0,0,
                             0,0,1,0,1),
                           nrow=5,
                           ncol=5)
colnames(incidence.matrix) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
rownames(incidence.matrix) <- c("1","2","3","4","5")
bg <- graph.incidence(incidence.matrix)
g <- bipartite.projection(bg)
g <- g$proj2
plot(g)
```

But following this method I lose the information concerning when two people have met.

How could I proceed to embed this information as attribute of the vertices?

Comment: Your code _does_ keep attributes for me, so maybe check your igraph version.

Comment: @GaborCsardi What's the attribute's name I should look for? This is my graph as by last line of script: `IGRAPH UNWB 5 6 -- 
+ attr: type (v/l), name (v/c), weight (e/n)`. My igraph version is 0.7.

Comment: `name (v/c)` and this comment must be at least 15 characters, so it now.